# Reloading UITableView keeps old data

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom view

```
MyView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

with a UITableView within (and some buttons and labels).

I have a notification from another view to populate the table with data form a sqlite3 database. I passed an array and after handle the notification I reload the table (*[tableView reloadData]*) with the new data (it has new data, I debug it).

Then it calls

```
(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

but doesn't refresh cells, it still old data. I debug and it reloads but doesn't refresh data.

What's the problem? Can I clear old cells or something like that?

Comment: What does your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method look like? Are you sure you're setting it every time, or just when the template cell (or whatever) is first created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably setting the data in your cell == nil block after dequeueing it.  In that case, move it out of that block and be sure that the data is set on every single cellForRowAtIndexPath call.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you ^^